# How to use Firebase authentication for Android app authentication with NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebase Authentication for authentication (email/password) in an Android application. From what I saw Firebase does not allow multiple simultaneous logged users, so if a user_1 a logs in from a device and then user_2 logs in as well, user_2 is the new current user logged.
So it is needed to use the Token validation mechanism provided by Firebase, but I really do not understand how to manage the expiration time of the tokens (that is 1 hour).
In the documentation it is written that the command:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)`

returns the token of the current user logged, and if the token is expired a fresh one token is returned.
My problem is that for being the currentUser the user must sign in to Firebase using:

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)`

Because my plan was to send to the Android client (via NodeJS) the token generated by Firebase when the Android user logs in, and then use such token every time for performing operations on Firebase.
Probably I am missing something but I don't understand how to handle this problem without having the Android user to logs in every hour.

(Another problem that I see in my approach: what happens if user_1 logs in and before calling the method for get the token of the currentUser, user_2 logs in becoming the new currentUser?)